# HTML to search Excel and display Result

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I am very new to html and JavaScript.

My project is to make a website in html that can search excel for user-defined criteria and display results back in the webpage.

Example: a user searches the ID number #1234, and the website then displays information like name, location, gender etc. That correspondences with that ID number (ID number in col A).

The data is in excel, typically one row per unique ID. And is currently in xlsx format but this can be changed.

Sorry for the lengthy question and lack of coding example. I have searched many different options however I cant even get those to work.

Any direction or help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is going to be a monumental task if you are beginning. I'd say you should start with a smaller project. Especially since you don't know where to start / what to search for on google. If however you can convert your data to json (assuming you own the data), that will be more reachable.

If you want to do it with excel data anyway, with javascript, there is [this parser for spread sheet that can help you](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx):

> Parser and writer for various spreadsheet formats. Pure-JS cleanroom
>   implementation from official specifications, related documents, and
>   test files. Emphasis on parsing and writing robustness, cross-format
>   feature compatibility with a unified JS representation, and ES3/ES5
>   browser compatibility back to IE6.
>
> This is the community version. We also offer a pro version with
>   performance enhancements, additional features by request, and
>   dedicated support.